# Running Ngrok in a container using docker

Tags: docker, ngrok

[https://github.com/gtriggiano/ngrok-tunnel ] runs ngrok inside a container. Ngrok is required to run in the container to avert security risks. But am facing problems after running the scripts, which generates the url

```
$ docker pull gtriggiano/ngrok-tunnel


$ docker run -it  -e "TARGET_HOST=localhost" -e "TARGET_PORT=3000" -p 4040 gtriggiano/ngrok-tunnel
```

[image]
am running my rails app on localhost:3000

is it my problem or can it be fixed by altering the scripts(inside the repo)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. if you execute -p with single number it's container port - host port is randomly assigned. 
Using -p, --publish ip:[hostPort]:containerPort at docker run can specify the the host port with the container port.

as of now the 4040 of container is exposed. Not sure if your service listens by default on it.

To get localhost port execute

```
docker ps
```

you'll see the actual port it's not listening on.

```
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                     COMMAND             CREATED              STATUS              PORTS                     NAMES
1aaaeffe789d        gtriggiano/ngrok-tunnel   "npm start"         About a minute ago   Up About a minute   0.0.0.0:32768->4040/tcp   wizardly_poincare
```

here it's listening on localhost:32768

Comment: so why is there TARGET_HOST and TARGET_PORT ? thanks for answering

Comment: and also when I am trying to run my rails app in the port specified I am getting error already in use

Comment: after starting the container. How do you run the application? Also one port can be given to one process only. So that's normal.

Comment: It's still unlear to me how the command has to be built to run the tunnel as expected, as `docker run -it  -e "TARGET_HOST=localhost" -e "TARGET_PORT=44332"  -p, --publish ip:44332:containerPort 4040 gtriggiano/ngrok-tunnel` gives me the same error as OP. Do I have to change my applications port to the randomly assigned one I get through `docker ps`?

Answer (score 5):

**I have started receiving the following error with this now, so this answer may not work for you any more: `Your ngrok-agent version "2.3.29" is too old. The minimum supported agent version for your account is "2.3.35". Please update to a newer version with` ngrok update`, by downloading from https://ngrok.com/download, or by updating your SDK version.`**

---

I couldn't get this working but switched to https://github.com/shkoliar/docker-ngrok and it works brilliantly.

In my case I added it to my docker-compose.yml file:

```
ngrok:
    image: shkoliar/ngrok:latest
    ports:
      - 4551:4551
    links:
      - web
    environment:
      - PARAMS=http -region=eu -authtoken=${NGROK_AUTH_TOKEN} localdev.docker:80
    networks:
      dev_net:
        ipv4_address: 10.5.0.10
```

And it's started with everything else when I do `docker-compose up -d`

Then there's a web UI at http://localhost:4551/ for you to see the status, requests, the ngrok URLs, etc.

The Github page does have examples of running it manually from the command line too though, rather than via docker-compose:

> Command-line Example The example below assumes that you have running
> web server docker container named dev_web_1 with exposed port 80.
>
> `docker run --rm -it --link dev_web_1 shkoliar/ngrok ngrok http dev_web_1:80`
>
> With command line usage, ngrok session is active until it
> won't be terminated by Ctrl+C combination.

Comment: Where are you setting the Ngrok token with this approach?

Comment: @Mitya Apologies, I must not have used the auth token when I initially wrote this answer and never updated it when we added it in. I've updated my answer to include it, it's just in the docker-compose.yml file.

You can hardcode it if you need to I guess - we've just got it in a Docker .env file so different people can have a different value on their machine easily.

Answer (score 2):

this composer works for me. Note that in the entrypoint command for ngrok you have to reference the other service by name

```
version: '3'
services: 
          
    yourwebserver:
        build:
            context: ./
            dockerfile: ...
            target: ...
        container_name: yourwebserver
        volumes:
            - ...
        ports:
            - ...
        extra_hosts:
            - 'host.docker.internal:host-gateway'
        depends_on: 
            - ngrok

            
    ngrok:
        image: ngrok/ngrok:alpine
        environment:
            NGROK_AUTHTOKEN: '...'
        command: 'http yourwebserver:80'        
        ports:
            - '4040:4040'
        expose:
            - '4040'
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if you have already solved this but when I was getting this error I could only solve it like this:

```
# docker-compose.yml

networks:
  - development
```

I also needed to expose the 3000 port of my web container because it still wasn't exposed.

```
# docker.compose.yml

web:
  expose:
    - "3000"
```

My container for the server running on development is also under the `development` network. The only parameters, I believe, you should pass for the container to execute are `image`, `ports`, `environment` with DOMAIN and PORT for the server container, a `link`, and an `expose` on your web container:

```
# docker-compose.yml

  ngrok:
    image: shkoliar/ngrok
    ports:
      - 4551:4551
    links:
      - web
    networks:
      - development
    environment:
      - DOMAIN=squad_web
      - PORT=3000
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually to make ngrok work with your docker container you can install it outside of your project just like the manual on their website says. And then add

```
  nginx:
    labels:
    - "traefik.http.routers.${PROJECT_NAME}_nginx.rule=Host(`${PROJECT_BASE_URL}`, `aaa-abc-xxx-140-177.eu.ngrok.io`)"
```

This particular example is for docker4drupal docker-compose file and traefik mapped as 80:80